# Resizing a vector an retrieving the value, Is this correct or can lead to segfault in any situation?

Tags: c++, vector

If you see in below example I have resized the vector to size `3` and I am storing the pointer `data1` at data[5] do you see this as a problem unless I am not storing more than 3 records.

This works absolutely flawless but is this right approach ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
 int age;
 int id;
};

int main()
{

 std::cout<<"inside main"<<std::endl;

 std::vector<Data*> data;

 data.resize(3);
 Data *data1 = new Data();
 std::cout<<"after resize"<<std::endl;
 data1-> age = 28;
 data1-> id = 5592;
 data[5] = data1;
 std::cout<<"after populate = ";
 std::cout<<data[5]->age<<std::endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: `data[5] = data1;` is undefined behaviour. Valid indexes for data are [0..2].

Comment: If you don't consider possible corruption of memory you don't own "a problem"... no

Comment: Chances are you don't need a vector of pointers.

Comment: Going out of bounds, no matter when or where or how, always leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just don't do it.

Comment: [] this does not do a bound check. try `data.at(5)` and see the difference.

Comment: Using `at` would lead to an other UB as exception would not be caught ;-)

Comment: @Ron Yeah that was pointed out [last time as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50703490/583833)

Comment: A related question: [What is the purpose of allocating a specific amount of memory for arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879198/what-is-the-purpose-of-allocating-a-specific-amount-of-memory-for-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @Jarod42 - That's not UB. `std::terminate` would be called. That's well defined.

Comment: If you want to store at a random index, perhaps [std::map<int, Data>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is what you need. With a map, `data[5] = data1;` would create an entry if it is not there already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `std::vector` is **not** a sparse container in the sense that calling  `data.resize(3)` allows you to assign 3 elements to the vector at any index of your choosing. **That is not the case.**

You can only assign to indexes 0, 1, and 2. The behaviour on your attempting to access `data[5]` is *undefined*.

It appears to be working on this occasion due to your C++ runtime library possibly allocating space for more elements than 3, as a useful optimisation to obviate memory fragmentation. Possibly you could tell by looking at the *capacity* of the vector. But **never** rely on the capacity being the upper bound of the index you can access.

Comment: I think that the statement "It appears to be working on this occasion due to your C++ runtime library possibly allocating space for more elements than 3" is incorrect. if you `resize()` a 10 space container into 3 then the elements between [3-9] will get destroyed.

Comment: @KostasRim: Not necessarily, but you should *regard* them as being destroyed.

Comment: @Bathsheba This is much more precise.

Comment: @Bathsheba sounds interesting, could you please provide some details ?

Comment: @KostasRim: All the standard says in the reduction case is that "the container is reduced to its first count elements". For a vector of pointers, for example, there's no explicit mention of the deleted pointers being set to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Bathsheba oh, I see so it's implementation defined. That was interesting. Thanks

Comment: @KostasRim: Do note one thing though: in the reduction case, the vector's *capacity* is **not** allowed to change. The reason for that is that all hell would be let loose with iterators on the retained elements.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't think he said that they would be set to `nullptr`? He said they would be *destroyed*. If they were class instances and not pointers, then their destructors would be called; that is what it means to say they are destroyed.

Comment: @Bathsheba specifically the pointers are not `delete`d, the (hypothetical) (no-op) ~*Data() is run on them

Comment: @SeanBurton: Indeed destructors are called if the elements to be removed are objects with destructors. But this has moved somewhat away from the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior. You're writing into memory you haven't allocated. `data` doesn't own past `data[2]`.

Comment: @VinayShukla That's the fun part with UB, sometimes it appears to work. And sometimes it crashes massively.

Comment: @VinayShukla: UB is UB.

Comment: That's because you're lucky in this case. Specifically, the memory happens to not contain any other data. If it does, you're corrupting it. Also, when data reallocates, your data[5] will not be copied. Try resizing to a high number after the assignment and check the contents of data[5].

Comment: @VinayShukla It is possible that _in this particular case_ nothing bad happens because the vector has already allocated storage for 5+ elements. But there is _absolutely no guarantee_ that it keeps working in this or any other case. Do not rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks I take my downvote back what would be the best approach then

Comment: @ravnsgaard "That's because you're unlucky in this case" ftfy. Failing noisily is better than failing silently

Comment: Right. Lucky is a loaded term in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The read on data[5] is undefined behaviour, because the `resize()` function changes the size of the vector to 3. (valid indexes [0..2]).

The problem with the `operator[]` is it does not throw an `exception` on an invalid index. If you are unsure, of whether or not an index is valid consider using the `.at()` member function which checks for `if(vector.size() <= index) // throw` (Keep in mind the the function performance is a little slower because  of the extra check and throw). Also, if you want to play around consider the `safe version of stl`.

Comment: Do you think stl maps would be a good approach with key and value `pair <int key, struct Data* data>` If I am not sure about the size

Comment: @KostasRim Yes thats true. But can you then explain why above code compiles even though out of bound ? I am not sure, if this is the case here.

Comment: @VinayShukla why are you resizing the vector? Just use the `.push_back()` member function to auto resize the vector.

Comment: @JeJo Exceptions are thrown on `runtime`. It will compile and it will crash but you will know why it happened, that is, you will know that you have `std::out_of_range`

Comment: @KostasRim Yes thats what I wanted to here in your answer actually.

Comment: @KostasRim this is a dummy code bro the actual application is bit different and needs to be resized as per the runtime value received for the number of devices hence resized. Push back keeps on adding records for a particular `portId` and thus having a vector creates 100s of records for 10 ports so I need to uniquely maintain it. 

Thus plan is to use a stl map. Plz undo the downvote to my question if possible.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @VinayShukla It does indeed sound as if `std::map` (or maybe `std::unordered_map`) may be a better fit for your use-case. Alternatively you can put `std::pair`s into a vector, but you'll have to do the book-keeping to avoid duplicates yourself.

Comment: @ravnsgaard don't you think map will prevent this headache of uniquely maintaining it.

Comment: @VinayShukla There are pros and cons. Yes, `std::map` will do the book-keeping for you, but the data structure is node-based and hence your data will likely be fragmented on the heap. `std::vector` guarantees contiguous memory layout, but will not prevent duplicates. You'll have to decide based on your use-case. If the data set is fairly small, the fragmentation of `std::map` may not matter. My suggestion would be to go for `std::map` and only change to `std::vector` for this if you find that it's a performance problem.

Comment: @ravnsgaard thanks I would go with vectors reason being I have commands to list all data and without knowing the key so it can become  a problem.